# Gender honorifics: "sir" and "miss"

Tags: work-environment, ethics, philippines

Is it offensive if I call older male co-workers that I'm not directly working under for as "sir" while I use "miss" for female co-worker? I feel like using "ma'am" should be reserved for women that are my boss, but using "mister" in lieu of "sir" is uncommon in the workplace. What should I use?

It has become awkward to refer to people a year or three older than me with honorifics as a sign of respect to their age but not as deferral in the workplace so that they can order me around(which they shouldn't and can't do) so most of the time I just call them by their first names.

Comment: What country/ region are you in?  Are you talking about customers?  Or other employees that you don't work with?  If we're talking about customers, your manager will undoubtedly know the organization's preferred approach.  I would expect "miss" to be a problematic way to refer to customers in most of the US but it's probably more likely to be acceptable in southern states.

Comment: I'm from the Philippines and I'm referring to the people in the workplace. In written correspondence I don't use "miss" ever but "ms.".

Comment: "the people in the workplace" and people "I don't work with" could both be read to mean either customers or other employees that you don't work with directly.  If you are working in the Philippines, that should be added as a tag.

Comment: People that work for the company then? I updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of sir (with no name), it's ma'am.  *Ms* is the equivalent of *Mr*, both of which require a surname suffixed to it.

For example:

> Good morning sir.
>
> Good morning ma'am.

For the *title*, then you need to suffix as such:

> Good morning, Mr Smith.
>
> Good morning, Ms Smith.

I would suggest that in the context given, the "ma'am" is more appropriate.  It's certainly what I get and would expect in that environment.

Comment: Mr or Ms is always fine, but Sir or Ma'am will show some respect. And that respect is a trade. I used to call sir/ma'am for people who are rich than me and higher paygrade. Because that's what I have to trade to them, in return I expect opportunities from them. That's all.

Comment: in many countries "Miss" is used alone as an honorific for teachers and other authority figures. It doesn't require a last name and doesn't carry an implication of marital status.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it offensive if I call older male co-workers that I'm not directly working under for as "sir" while I use "miss" for female co-worker?

At least in the US, *Miss* generally refers to a young woman. To address an older woman in a neutral way, use *Ms* (pronounced "miz") with her last name. You can use "sir" to address any adult male, regardless of age.

I don't think it's ever *offensive* to show someone extra respect by using an honorific, but when you're dealing with coworkers it might be a little off-putting if you overdo it because you put them in the situation where they have to wonder if you expect them to address you the same way. Too much formality can become a barrier to easy communication.

I think it's most common for coworkers to be on a first name basis even when there's a significant age difference, and even if they don't work together directly. That's not universal, though, and it depends on local culture, your office culture, and other person's position. When in doubt, it's never impolite to just ask: *How should I address you?*

> It has become awkward to refer to people a year or three older than me with honorifics as a sign of respect to their age but not as deferral in the workplace...so most of the time I just call them by their first names.

That's almost certainly the right choice.

Sometimes people will use "sir" or "ma'am" in a slightly humorous way, much as someone might hold a door open with an elaborate flourish. They might hand you a report with a "Here you go, sir!" or let you pass in or out of a room first with an "After you, sir!" In these situations it's never wrong to respond in kind, but it's not necessary to maintain that level of formality beyond the end of that particular interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the UK, so cultural norms are different, but outside of the military or police force, people almost always refer to their coworkers by their first name regardless of age or position. Do you and your coworkers wear identity badges? At my company everyone's badge just has first and last name on it. If yours have Mr./Mrs./Ms. on them then maybe it might be appropriate to use honorifics, if not first name is probably fine. Your best guide is probably just to observe what everyone else does.

Answer (score 0):

again sounds like a cultural issue.

In my culture and office environment I only call sir for people whose pay grade is higher than me. Because they clearly deserve that thing. And they know by saying "sir", this guy silently want to come to my pay grade and that's a good motivation.

It's not depend on the gender at all. There are rich people who are rich from both genders,so if he/she is rich , don't afraid to call him sir or mam. Rich people have opportunities on their hand, the more you respect them little time it take to be like them and be rich like them. It's all about trade, you don't have money, so you give what you got the respect. Very sooner you'll be rich.